# Running an Angular PWA on server without https

Tags: angular, docker, progressive-web-apps

I'm working on an Angular PWA and I have a problem when trying to use through the network.
I'm hosting the PWA in a docker container. It works perfectly if I run and execute from the localhost. But at the moment I want to access outside localhost, using the IP address, Chrome stops asking if I want to install the app. However, if I try from a mobile device, click on the 3 dots beside URL and click on Add to my home screen, it seems to work as expected.

I've read it has to do with the lack of https. Could be?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: "Add to home screen" used on a website that does not pass all the requirements for a PWA will only add a shortcut to the website. It does not install the PWA. HTTPS is a core requirement for an installable PWA.

Comment: Thanks for your help.